# Python SnowflakeOperator setup snowflake_default

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Good day, I cannot find how to do basic setup to `airflow.contrib.operators.snowflake_operator.SnowflakeOperator`to connect to snowflake. `snowflake.connector.connect` works fine.

When I do it with `SnowflakeOperator` :

`op = snowflake_operator.SnowflakeOperator(sql = "create table test(*****)", task_id = '123')`

I get the

`airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The conn_id`snowflake_default`isn't defined`

I tried to insert in backend sqlite db

`INSERT INTO connection(
    conn_id, conn_type, host
    , schema, login, password
    , port, is_encrypted, is_extra_encrypted
) VALUES (*****)`

But after it I get an error:

`snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 251001: None: Account must be specified`.

Passing `account` kwarg into `SnowflakeOperator` constructor does not help. It seems I cannot pass account into db or into constructor, but it's required.

Please help me, let me know ***what data*** I should insert into backend local db to be able to connect via `SnowflakeOperator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Admin -> Connections and update `snowflake_default` connection like this:

based on source code `airflow/contrib/hooks/snowflake_hook.py:53` we need to add extras like this:

```
{
    "schema": "schema",
    "database": "database",
    "account": "account",
    "warehouse": "warehouse"
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but only if i added in extra what those params you wrote + "account" param. Please update the answer and i'll mark it as accepted. ```extra : {"database": "*****", "schema": "*****", "warehouse": "*****", "account": "****"}``` Is an info i asked for

Answer (score 0):

With this context:

```sh
$ airflow version
2.2.3
$ pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.4.1
$ pip install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==2.5.0
```

You have to specify the Snowflake Account and Snowflake Region twice like this:

```sh
airflow connections add 'my_snowflake_db' \
    --conn-type 'snowflake' \
    --conn-login 'my_user' \
    --conn-password 'my_password' \
    --conn-port 443 \
    --conn-schema 'public' \
    --conn-host 'my_account_xyz.my_region_abc.snowflakecomputing.com' \
    --conn-extra '{ "account": "my_account_xyz", "warehouse": "my_warehouse", "region": "my_region_abc" }'
```

Otherwise it doesn't work throwing the Python exception:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 251001: 251001: Account must be specified
```

I think this might be due to that `airflow` command parameter `--conn-host` that is expecting a full domain with subdomain (the `my_account_xyz.my_region_abc`), that usually for Snowflake are specified as query parameters in a way similar to this template (although I did not check all the combinations of the command `airflow connections add` and the DAG execution):

```
"snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}{region}{cloud}/{database}/{schema}?role={role}&warehouse={warehouse}&timezone={timezone}"
```

Then a dummy Snowflake DAG like this `SELECT 1;` will find its own way to the Snowflake cloud service and will work:

```py
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow.models import DAG

# https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/operators/snowflake.html
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator

my_dag = DAG(
    "example_snowflake",
    start_date=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    default_args={"snowflake_conn_id": "my_snowflake_db"},
    schedule_interval="0 0 1 * *",
    tags=["example"],
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=10),
)

sf_task_1 = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id="sf_task_1",
    dag=my_dag,
    sql="SELECT 1;",
)
```